# Query stale AD computer accounts with computer name exceptions

Tags: powershell

Needing to query stale AD computer accounts, however we have VDI "Golden Images" that I do not want to disable.  I thought that I could just use "Where-Object" to filter out the name but it fails.  Can someone help point out where I'm going wrong?

```
Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate -Filter {lastLogonDate -lt $then} | Where-Object {$Name -Notlike "*VDI*"} | FT Name,lastLogonDate
```

This code gives me all stale (90 day old computer accounts), however it still shows computer accounts with VDI in the name.

Comment: `$Name` would work out to a null variable here which would not match "VDI". `$_.Name` is what you want. Also I think you could just add that clause into your `-Filter` anyway so you dont have to post process

Comment: Yes!  $_.Name worked great.  I'm very new to PowerShell so I'm not sure how to add it to my -Filter statement though.  Also, this is my first time asking a question.  How do I mark your answer as correct?  I don't see the check mark as described in the FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) for the help!

> $Name would work out to a null variable here which would not match "VDI". $_.Name is what you want. Also I think you could just add that clause into your -Filter anyway so you dont have to post process

I used the below answer:

```
Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate -Filter {lastLogonDate -lt $then} | Where-Object {$_.Name -Notlike "*VDI*"} | FT Name,lastLogonDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate -Filter {lastLogonDate -lt $then} | Where-Object {$Name -Notmatch "VDI"} | FT Name,lastLogonDate
```